# Is "send me it" or "send it to me" correct?

Tags: grammar

I would like you to correct if 'send me it' is grammatically correct

Comment: Personally, I'd be quite happy with *Can you send it me as soon as possible?*, but then again I'm happy with *Can you open me the door, please?* which might not suit everyone.

Comment: Related: [send it me](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372235/is-it-correct-to-say-send-it-me)

Comment: I appreciate that you have answered my query. And I have a suggestion on the example that you have provided. I don't think, _send it me_ would be appropriate to use.

Comment: "Send me it" sounds wrong, but "send me the print-out" (e.g.,) is completely okay.

Answer (score 5):

"Send it to me" is correct and more commonly used. Although "send me it" is grammatically correct, it's not commonly used in formal writing.

Comment: General directions are often given, like "send it here" or "send it there." But with explicit recipients, we normally say "sent it to me" or "send it to her."

Comment: We avoid pairs of personal pronouns, but other pro-forms are allowed: Send me that.  Send me those.  *Send me them.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia (and my own sensibility),

> in some dialects the former *[using two objects sequentially with no preposition, as in "He gave me the ball"]* is considered ungrammatical, or at least unnatural-sounding, when both objects are pronouns (as in "He gave me it").
>   <sub>*- from Wikipedia's "[Ditransitive Verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb)" page*</sub>

So, if you want to avoid the possibility that some reader will believe that you have made a mistake, or that the usage will "stick out" and break the reader's flow, you should stick with *Send it to me*, which uses the form that the same page mentions "is grammatically correct in every case".